# Is there a way to avoid method calling repetition?

Tags: c#, .net

I am building a game where several methods are chained to other and need to called behind the scenes. For example, when a soldier needs to leave the castle, the gate needs to be opened and then closed as soon as he leaves:

```
public void MoveTheGate(bool openTheGate)
{
    if (openTheGate)
    {
        //  code for: open the gate
    }
    else
    {
        //  code for: close the gate
    }
}

public void GetOutOfTheCastle()
{
    MoveTheGate(true);

    //  code for: get out of the castle

    MoveTheGate(false);
}
```

The same is true for when a messenger from another kingdom reaches the castle, the `MoveTheGate()` method has to be called both in the beginning and in the end of the messenger's entrance to the castle.

Is there a more delicate way to achieve this?

Comment: Working code is off-topic for StackOverflow. You might wanna take a look at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: It all depends on what the commented out code is. If there is a way to reuse a lot of it, then definitely keep the single method. Post the full code on Code Review as @Pierre-LucPineault suggested.

Comment: Beware, though, Code Review does not allow stub code.  You will have to post the whole method(s).

Comment: Hi @Pierre-LucPineault, thanks for the suggestion, I am not looking for my code to be reviewed, I am looking for more elegant ways to deal with the ugliness that is caused within my code by having to repeat these methods continuously. The code above is just an example.

Comment: Alright. But also keep in mind methods are made to be reused. Your code is fine that way (although I'd definitely separate that bool method into two methods), the other options would probably reduce the readability or introduce overdesign. Depends heavily on your current architecture too, you could probably hide all that repetitive behavior with a simple inheritance.

Comment: I would say the code is fine. Sure, you could find a way to wrap it in a block like the answers below suggest, but what if someone kills the gatekeeper while the gate is open? :)

Answer (score 2):

you could do

```
OpenGate(()=>
  { stuff to do with gate open }
);
```

where OpenGate is

```
public void OpenGate(Action action)
{
    try
    {
      MoveTheGate(true);
      action();
   }
   finally 
   {
    MoveTheGate(false);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be total overkill, but you could always implement `IDisposable` then use a `using` block. That's a nice way to "make sure" it happens.

If you set up a class that called some given action on dispose,

```
public class DelegateDisposable : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Action action;

    public DelegateDisposable(Action action)
    {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(this.action != null)
        {
            this.action();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
private IDisposable OpenGate()
{
    MoveTheGate(true);
    return new DelegateDisposable(() => MoveTheGate(false));
}
```

And use it like this:

```
public void GetOutOfTheCastle()
{
    using (OpenGate())
    {
        //  code for: get out of the castle
    }
}
```

A nice advantage of this approach is that it doesn't mess with your callstack, although again, it does have some overhead. But if you brought `DelegateDisposable` into some utility class, it could probably be useful for something else as well.

Comment: While this DOES indeed work, it feels dirty to implement IDisposable when there is no required cleanup of unmanaged resources.

Comment: @DavidL It's a trade-off between what you do to the call-stack, how clean the code is, and your principles. I've seen--although I can't think of where--a few projects that I respected using `IDisposable` for things like this, and I don't mind it too much. I kind of view "the gate" as a resource that needs clean-up, although I definitely see your point--it's not exactly the same thing as an open stream or anything.

Answer (score 1):

I would be impartial to an inheritance pattern that forces you to perform actions within the context of a base, inherited abstract class.  The reason I believe this is preferable is because it allows you to easily encapsulate your Gate opening and closing and does not expose either the conditions for that to occur or that functionality outside of an inherited scenario.

```
public void Main()
{
    var x = new InheritedAction();
}

public abstract class BaseGateAction
{
    public void PerformBaseAction(Action actionToPerformWhileGateIsOpen)
    {
        Open();
        actionToPerformWhileGateIsOpen();
        Close();
    }

    private void Open()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Gate has been opened");
    }

    private void Close()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Gate has been closed");
    }
}

public class InheritedAction : BaseGateAction
{
    public InheritedAction()
    {
        PerformBaseAction(() => 
            Console.WriteLine("Attack the dragon while the gate is open"));

        PerformBaseAction(() => 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Attack the dragon while the gate is open");
            Console.WriteLine("The dragon is victorious and you have been devoured");
        });
    }
}
```

This code sample outputs the following for both PerformBaseAction method calls respectively:

```
Gate has been opened
Attack the dragon while the gate is open
Gate has been closed

Gate has been opened
Attack the dragon while the gate is open
The dragon is victorious and you have been devoured
Gate has been closed
```

This would allow for not only better code reuse, but far more encapsulated logic.  You could always add additional exposed methods that take pre-conditions or post-conditions that would affect whether or not you could open the gate.

```
public abstract class BaseGateAction
{
    ....    
    public void PerformBaseActionWithPrecondition(Func<bool> precondition, Action actionToPerformWhileGateIsOpen)
    {
        if (precondition())
        {
            PerformBaseAction(actionToPerformWhileGateIsOpen);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The gate could not be opened!");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

This could be called as follows:

```
PerformBaseActionWithPrecondition<bool>(
        () => true == false,
        () => Console.WriteLine("Attack!")
    );
```

And would output:

```
The gate could not be opened!
```